# How to append values repeatedly on to a sheet based on a value in an object?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm looking to append values repeatedly on to a sheet based on a multiplier value.
The values will come from html form fields. But for now I hard coded all the values and the multiplier.

So far this is code that works to repeat(post) the values as expected. But it does not assign a new Id to each line.

Here is what happens with this current function. Note that all 10 id for JOHN is the same. It should be consecutive numbers.

[image]

```js
function RepeatValuesBasedOnMultiplier2(fieldData) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1h6Mi0A_nr7IHhx1cTXWGXW43pI2-rnZxdHqk9-QgA08');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('ROBOT');
  var rg = sh.getRange(4,1,sh.getLastRow()-3,1);//modified you number of row was incorrect
  
  var vA = rg.getValues();
  //var maxNum = Math.max(...vA.map(function(r){return r[0];}));//array flattened and spread

    var ar = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], rg.getValues());
  var maxNum = Math.max.apply(null, ar)+1;
  var ts = new Date();
    var FirstName = "JOHN";//this will come from an html form field
  var LastName = "SMITH";//this will come from an html form field
  var multiplier = "10";//this will come from an html form field
  
   var sartNum = 1;//this will come from an html form field
  var NotaForneID = "6655456"+" | ";

   var ds = "26/07/2020";
  var tA=ds.split('/'); 
 
  
    for(var i=0;i<multiplier;i++) {
    sh.appendRow([maxNum++,FirstName, LastName,NotaForneID+sartNum++,new Date(tA[2],tA[1]-1,Number(tA[0])+28)]
/*I need to get the dates to be incremented by 28 days. As it is now it just increases once and repeats the same date on all new rows*/

);
  }  
  return maxNum;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `reflecting the maxNum for each new repeated row.`? Are you just wanting to post the same data x number of times, where x is `fieldData.multiplier`?

Comment: Hi, indeed I need to post the same data x number of times, but the maxNum is an unique id and I want each new repeated row to have it's on id.

Comment: Can you share your data sheet? After you've obtained `maxNum` it's not clear where the next is meant to come from, is it the next largest from `ar`?

Comment: I have created the sample data with the hard coded variables so each new line has the new id. link to the sheet and script https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h6Mi0A_nr7IHhx1cTXWGXW43pI2-rnZxdHqk9-QgA08/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you looking for?

```
function RepeatValuesBasedOnMultiplier(fieldData) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1h6Mi0A_nr7IHhx1cTXWGXW43pI2-rnZxdHqk9-QgA08');
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('ROBOT');
  var rg=sh.getRange(4,1,sh.getLastRow()-3,1);//modified you number of row was incorrect
  var vA=range.getValues();
  var maxNum=Math.max(...vA.map(function(r){return r[0];}));//array flattened and spread
  var ts=new Date();
  var multiplier = fieldData.multiplier;
  for(var i=0;i<fieldata.multiplier;i++) {
    sh.appendRow([maxnum++,fieldData.firstname,fieldData.lastName,ts,""]);
  }  
  return maxNum;
}
```

You haven't explained how maxnum is unique nor have you supplied precise information about the origin of firstName and lastName so I assumed the parameter as the origin.

If you wish a better answer then provide more information.

Please note: I do not follow links to spreadsheets everything needed in your question must be posted in your question.

I'm not sure if this helps but for whatever it's worth:

```
function add28daysToEachRow() {
  let dt=new Date();
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  let vs=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(i>0) {
     r.push(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()+(i*28)),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy"));
    }else{
      r.push('');
    }
  });
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Okay here it is:

```
function RepeatValuesBasedOnMultiplier2(fieldData) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1h6Mi0A_nr7IHhx1cTXWGXW43pI2-rnZxdHqk9-QgA08');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('ROBOT');
  var rg = sh.getRange(4,1,sh.getLastRow()-3,1);//modified you number of row was incorrect
  var vA = rg.getValues();
  var ar = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], rg.getValues());
  var maxNum = Math.max.apply(null, ar)+1;
  var ts = new Date();
  var FirstName = "JOHN";//this will come from an html form field
  var LastName = "SMITH";//this will come from an html form field
  var multiplier = "10";//this will come from an html form field
  var sartNum = 1;//this will come from an html form field
  var NotaForneID = "6655456"+" | ";
  var ds = "26/07/2020";//start date
  var sd=new Date(2020,6,25);//months are Jan - Dec = 0 - 11
  for(var i=0;i<multiplier;i++) {
    var dt=new Date(sd.getFullYear(),sd.getMonth(),sd.getDate()+Number(i*28))
    var dts=Utilities.formatDate(dt,Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"dd/MM/yyyy");
    sh.appendRow([maxNum++,FirstName, LastName,NotaForneID+sartNum++,dts]);
  }  
  return maxNum;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Cooper, thank you for the code and advice on how to formulate the question. Your code is very close to what I need. I've edited(with some minor alterations) it and resubmitted in my original question. I've also added an image of what the expected result is.

Comment: It still doesn't explain how you calculcated maxnum unless it's simply maxnum++

Comment: The maxNum is the maximum number in the last row of column A plus 1.

Comment: Okay so it is maxnum++.

Comment: That's correct. I have edited the code in my question.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you for your help. Everything works as expected.

Comment: If I may ask one more thing? As I'm developing my real app, I realized that one of my values is a date **dd/mm/yyyy** and I have to add 28 days in the same dynamic to each of the submitted rows, not just copy. Would please guide me in the right direction?

Comment: function add28days(ds) {
  //ds is in the form dd/mm/yyyy
  var tA=ds.split('/');
  return new Date(t[2],t[1],Number(t[0])+28);
}

Comment: I get the part`var ds = "30/06/2020"; var tA=ds.split('/'); var add28Days = new Date(tA[2],tA[1],Number(tA[0])+28);` that I can add the days to the value and it works. The only thing is how do I implement it in the for loop `sh.appendRow([maxNum++,FirstName, LastName,add28Days]);` So that each row would be incremented by 28day?

Comment: Do you want it in the timestamp?

Comment: It's not in the timestamp. Just like the maxNum++ I also need the date to be increased by 28 day for each new row.

Comment: I've tried it this way but no luck. `for(var i=0;i<multiplier;i++) {
    sh.appendRow([maxNum++,FirstName, LastName,NotaForneID,new Date(tA[2],tA[1]-1,Number(tA[0])+28)]);
  }`

Comment: Look at the example I put in my answer.

Comment: I did look at your example and I'm great-full for it. But I can't figure out how to join it with my current working code. I've placed the full code in my question. Maybe that could make it more clear or perhaps I should ask another question in the forum.

Comment: Please make it clear in the code where you want it to go.

Comment: Sure, I made a comment under the  `sh.appendRow(` line. I'm stuck and desperate. There is also an image illustration of the expected results.

Comment: That's super helpful. Thank you so much! That is  tremendous.